# VSTO WPF ContextMenu.MenuItem Click outside a TaskPane not raised

Tags: wpf, excel, vsto, contextmenu

The Click Event form a Context Menu Item is not raised when the cursor is outside the taskpane.
I have no idea how get it working.
90% of the time, the click is outside the task Pane.

[image]

When the context menu is openned, the sub menus are often displayed outside the task pane (see picture below).
In such cases, the click event from the context Menu is not raised.

I have absolutly no idea how to make this work.

Any ideas?

Comment: +1 a similar issue to mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526118/bug-cant-choose-dates-on-a-datepicker-that-fall-outside-a-floating-vsto-add-in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Custom Task Pane has focus problems with WPF Context Menus. Look [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/432998/excel-2007-vsto-custom-task-pane-with-wpf-context-menu-has-focus-problems).

I have the same problems. Actually I use one of the recommended workarounds ([Dispatcher Frame](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/432998/excel-2007-vsto-custom-task-pane-with-wpf-context-menu-has-focus-problems)). Is is working, but I am not very happy with this clumsy solution.

Comment: Thanks. Note that you should have the CustomPane reference, either wen declared in xaml. This solution may freeze your app if not correctly implemented. And i have to use e.Source rather than LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource) but not sure.

Comment: if office app get locked try this : 

Public Sub ContextMenuClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)

     Dispatcher.ExitAllFrames()

end sub

Comment: +1 LogicalTreeHelper condition didn't work for me either. I simply commented it out and it works now. Thanks @Dirk & Avlin

Comment: Unfortunately, It doesn't work. It blocks other events. Apparently Frame.Continue = False never executes...