# How to add a new CustomTaskPane to each new opened Excel Document?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am developing a VSTO Add-in for Excel and I want to add a new CustomTaskPane (**userAdminTaskPane**) to each new opened Excel document by this code and make it visible:

```
public static void CreateUploadFile(string name)
        {
            string fileName = String.Concat(name, ".txt");
            string filePath = Path.Combine(Properties.Settings.Default.workingDir,fileName);
            File.WriteAllText(filePath, Properties.Resources.UploadTemplate,Encoding.Unicode);
            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Workbooks.OpenText(filePath,Excel.XlPlatform.xlMSDOS,1,Excel.XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited,Excel.XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote,false,true);
            mainTaskPane userAdminTaskPane = new mainTaskPane();
        }
```

How can I do this? should I handle specific events or can I do this for new Excel Documents created using this method only?

Comment: If you haven't already, take a look at the Add-in Express library. It makes adding ribbons etc much easier, as well as helps out a lot in dealing with differences in all the office versions.

Comment: Perhaps set it up like I have here in repro steps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10526118/495455

Comment: Are you using a ribbon in your project? If so, you can use the [`Ribbon_Load`](https://github.com/Excel-projects/Script-Help/blob/master/CS/Scripts/Ribbon.cs#L148-L187) event. Here is one of my [Excel Addins](https://github.com/Excel-projects/Script-Help) for reference

Comment: @aduguid yes i am, a button in the ribbon calls this method.

Comment: @MarcBernier well i can't use 3rd party library for this, since this would overkill for this specific project. Thanks.

Comment: I'd work with the appropriate events, such as `WorkbookOpen`,  `NewWorkbook` `Workbook.BeforeClose`. As I recall, that's also the approach Microsoft uses in its documentation for handling task panes in the pseudo-SDI environment. Here's the documentation article, but Excel is not represented as the article was written before it was forced into pseudo-SDI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/custom-task-panes?view=vs-2019